# Apache POI не загружается в Maven

Tags: java, maven, apache-poi

Необходимо написать программу, где значения берутся из excel файла.

```java
void initialize() {
    but6.setOnAction(event -> {
        try {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Super Sany\\IdeaProjects\\asd\\Сила.xlsx"));
            XSSFWorkbook woorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook (file);
            XSSFSheet sheet = woorkbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                Iterator<cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    cell cel = cellIterator.next();
                    switch (cel.getCellType()) {
                        case cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            System.out.printf("%.0f", cel.getNumericCellValue());
                            break;
                        case cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            System.out.println(cel.getStringCellValue());
                            break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println( );
            }
            file.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Что-то не так");
        }
    });
}
```

Проблемы:

1. Не видит библиотеку
2. Не видит зависимость в `pom.xml` файле
   Пытался решить проблему, вставляя в pom.xml файл этот фрагмент

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

но возникает ошибка `Dependency org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.1.0 not found`

Comment: Не могли бы Вы предоставить попытки решения ваших проблем? Это можно сделать, обновив вопрос кнопкой [править]

Comment: Код вообще не причем, покажите полный код из pom файла

Comment: И уточните среду разработки, зависимости подгружаются вообще ?